# How to loop over a response element in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scraper

I am trying to code a scraper with Scrapy for Python. At this point, I am trying to get the name of the webpage and all the outbound links within the page. The output should be a dictionary like this

```
        {'link': [u'Link1'], 'title': [u'Page title']}
```

I have created this code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy import Selector
from socialmedia.items import SocialMediaItem

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'smm'
    allowed_domains = ['*']
    start_urls = ['http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media']
    def parse(self, response):
        items =[]
        for link in response.xpath("//a"):
            item = SocialMediaItem()
            item['title'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
            item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
            yield items
```

Could anyone help me to get this result?
I've adapted the code from this page http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/05/scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/

updating the code without the deprecated functions.
Thank you so much!

Dani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate all of the links and extract links and titles.

Get all `a` tags via `//a` xpath and extract `text()` and `@href`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.xpath("//a"):
        item = SocialMediaItem()
        item['title'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
        item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
        yield item
```

This yields:

```
{'link': [u'#mw-navigation'], 'title': [u'navigation']}
{'link': [u'#p-search'], 'title': [u'search']}
...
{'link': [u'/wiki/Internet_forum'], 'title': [u'Internet forums']}
...
```

Also, note that there are [`Link Extractors`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) built-in into Scrapy:

> LinkExtractors are objects whose only purpose is to extract links from
>   web pages (scrapy.http.Response objects) which will be eventually
>   followed.

Comment: Thanks alecxe. I get this error when I use 'yield' 2014-11-28 18:31:30+0100 [smm] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list' in <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media>. When using 'return' it gives no error but it doesn't save anything to a file. How would you use a link extractor? I've updated the code.

Comment: @DaniValverde please use the exact `parse()` method i've provided - would not result into an error.

Comment: Thanks alecxe, for some reason it was giving an error the first time I used it.